# Using Chinese to build a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, dictionary, cjk

so this is my first time here, and also I am new to the world of Python. I am studying Chinese also and I wanted to create a program to review Chinese vocabulary using a dictionary. Here is the code that I normally use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8-*-

dictionary = {"Hello" : "你好"} # Simple example to save time

print(dictionary)
```

The results I keep getting are something like:

```
{'hello': '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'}
```

I have also trying adding a "u" to the beginning of the string with the Chinese characters, and even the method ".encode('utf-8'), yet no of these seem to work. I normally work off of the Geany IDE. I have tried to check out all of the preferences, and I have read [the PEP web page](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) along with many of the other questions posted. It is funny, it works with strings and the raw_input method, but nothing else...

Comment: Just for note, your code works fine with Python3.

Comment: I am using Python 3, the result I copied and pasted directly here...

Comment: No you're not using python3 because of the hashbang and because Python3 never displays `'\xNN'` but `'\uNNNN'` for chars biggers than 127 it can't show (not your case). Change the first line to `python3` and be happy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When printing a dict, (e.g. `print(dictionary)`), the `repr`s  of the keys and values are displayed.

Instead, try:

```
dictionary = {u"Hello" : u"你好"} 
for key,value in dictionary.iteritems():
    print(u'{k} --> {v}'.format(k=key,v=value))
```

yields:

```
Hello --> 你好
```

Comment: Current versions of Python allow you to do it as `'{} --> {}'.format(key, value)`, I believe. (2.7 onward, at least.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the characters if you print the values directly:

```
>>> d = {"Hello" : "你好"}
>>> print d["Hello"]
你好
```