# Character Decoding encoded string back to original state python

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm using python 2.7. I have a string that when I map to in a dictionary get's encoded. This is the string `u'cn-员工股票权益'` and this is the encoded version `u'cn-\u5458\u5de5\u80a1\u7968\u6743\u76ca'`. When put it a dictionary for example below it's getting encoded.

```
Python 2.7
new_dict = {}
new_dict['random_string'] = u'cn-员工股票权益'
new_dict['random_string']
u'cn-\u5458\u5de5\u80a1\u7968\u6743\u76ca'
```

This is how I'm trying to decode `u'cn-\u5458\u5de5\u80a1\u7968\u6743\u76ca'.decode('utf-8')` but I keep on getting the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-8: ordinal not in range(128)`

I would like to retrieve the original value that was placed in the dictionary and not the encoded value. Using this tool `https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php` I'm able to decode it back to the original state I wonder what algorithm they're using. I have tried a number of solutions from stack overflow however I haven't been able to achieve the desired results. Solutions I have tried include;

- [UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827396/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe7-in-position-0-ordinal)
- [how to print chinese word in my code.. using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688020/how-to-print-chinese-word-in-my-code-using-python)
- [How to decode a unicode string Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083374/how-to-decode-a-unicode-string-python)

Comment: What IDE do you use? I tried this code and seems fine with encoding, characters looks the same.

Comment: Try running this in the terminal
```
new_dict = {}
new_dict['random_string'] = u'cn-员工股票权益'
new_dict['random_string']

```

Comment: I'm using python 2 btw

Comment: It's not encoded, it's just a different representation.  Do `print new_dict['random_string']` and you'll see the Chinese characters.  See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988213/using-chinese-to-build-a-dictionary-in-python) for example.

Comment: Ohhh.. okay thank you @snakecharmerb